# How do I set a dataset's DisplayFormat to match the Windows currency format?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I am looking for a way to read the default currency related formatting information stored in Windows and build a format string, including the formatting for negative numbers, that I can use as the DisplayFormat of a dataset field.

For instance, In C# there is the format "C" for currency (see [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)).

For example (I ran it in linqpad):

```cs
String.Format("{0:C}", -120)
```

It prints `($120.00)`, which matches my Windows settings.

In Delphi I would need a function that looks at the `TFormatSettings` properties and builds the currency format string, something like this: `$,0.00;($,0.00)` (I am using English-US default settings).

I'm trying to work around an issue in the DevExpress quantum grid where the SUM footer aggregate for a column with currency values doesn't format negative numbers as defined by the OS settings.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? Most versions have a [`TFormatSettings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings) record available for retrieving the OS's default formatting values, eg: `Fmt := TFormatSettings.Create; // use Fmt.CurrencyString, Fmt.CurrencyFormat, Fmt.CurrencyDecimals, and Fmt.NegCurrFormat as needed...`

Comment: XE8. Yes, that is correct, but I hoped there is already a function that does that. I am searching now the source code...

Comment: Since you already know about TFormatSettings, what is the actual problem you are having using it?  Please show the code you have tried so far.  BTW, have you tried filing a bug report with DevExpress?

Comment: Have you looked at Delphi's [`SysUtils.FormatCurr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatCurr) function yet?  Or the `m` (money) specifier of [`SysUtils.Format()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format)?

Comment: I am in a time crunch and I was hoping there is already a function that does that somewhere buried in the Delphi API or somewhere else. To save time I thought of asking the question here. Chances someone came across this before are high.

Comment: It looks like you've given up too soon. Try some more research. Your time crunch is your problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Agreed :-)

Comment: @costa: "*To save time I thought of asking the question here*" - StackOverflow is not a real-time system. Grepping the RTL source code for uses of `TFormatSetting`'s currency fields would have taken less time, just saying ;-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I did both. And more brains are better than one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the code below. The first two functions are from data\Data.FMTBcd.pas.

One thing I noticed doing some testing, if I change the Decimal Symbol or the Digit grouping symbol in Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Additional Settings -> Currency tab, TFormatSettings doesn't read those new values, it always returns the dot as the decimal separator and the comma as the thousands separator. Instead, it uses these settings from the Numbers tab.

```
function AddCurrencySymbol(const Value, CurrSymbol: string; const CurrFormat: Byte): string;
begin
  case CurrFormat of
    0: Result := Format('%s%s', [CurrSymbol, Value]);
    1: Result := Format('%s%s', [Value, CurrSymbol]);
    2: Result := Format('%s %s', [CurrSymbol, Value]);
    3: Result := Format('%s %s', [Value, CurrSymbol]);
  end;
end;

{   0 = '($1)'      4 = '(1$)'      8 = '-1 $'      12 = '$ -1'
    1 = '-$1'       5 = '-1$'       9 = '-$ 1'      13 = '1- $'
    2 = '$-1'       6 = '1-$'      10 = '1 $-'      14 = '($ 1)'
    3 = '$1-'       7 = '1$-'      11 = '$ 1-'      15 = '(1 $)'  }
function AddNegCurrencySymbol(const Value, CurrSymbol: string; const CurrFormat: Byte): string;
begin
  case CurrFormat of
    0: Result := Format('(%s%s)', [CurrSymbol, Value]);
    1: Result := Format('-%s%s', [CurrSymbol, Value]);
    2: Result := Format('%s-%s', [CurrSymbol, Value]);
    3: Result := Format('%s%s-', [CurrSymbol, Value]);
    4: Result := Format('(%s%s)', [Value, CurrSymbol]);
    5: Result := Format('-%s%s', [Value, CurrSymbol]);
    6: Result := Format('%s-%s', [Value, CurrSymbol]);
    7: Result := Format('%s%s-', [Value, CurrSymbol]);
    8: Result := Format('-%s %s', [Value, CurrSymbol]);
    9: Result := Format('-%s %s', [CurrSymbol, Value]);
   10: Result := Format('%s %s-', [Value, CurrSymbol]);
   11: Result := Format('%s %s-', [CurrSymbol, Value]);
   12: Result := Format('%s %s', [CurrSymbol, Value]);
   13: Result := Format('%s -%s', [Value, CurrSymbol]);
   14: Result := Format('(%s- %s)', [CurrSymbol, Value]);
   15: Result := Format('(%s %s)', [Value, CurrSymbol]);
  end;
end;

function DefaultCurrencyFormat(formatSettings: TFormatSettings): String;
begin

 if formatSettings.CurrencyDecimals > 0 then
   Result := '0' + formatSettings.DecimalSeparator + StringOfChar('0', formatSettings.CurrencyDecimals)
 else
   Result := '0';

 Result := formatSettings.ThousandSeparator + Result;

 Result := AddCurrencySymbol(Result, formatSettings.CurrencyString, formatSettings.CurrencyFormat)
        + ';' + AddNegCurrencySymbol(Result, formatSettings.CurrencyString, formatSettings.NegCurrFormat)

end;
```